# I need to find Excel equation to concatenate the values in column Y when the Values in column N is constant

Tags: excel, vba, performance, excel-formula

=TRIM((TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE,TRIM(IF(N:N=$N2,Y:Y," "))))), This is the equation i have but when fll in the column which is more than 10,000 rows, the performance became too slow and took around 30 min to make the calculation,

New equation or modify this equation to get higher performance [image]

Comment: Why are you referencing entire columns? `N:N` is equivalent to `N1:N1048576`, and so `N:N=$N2` is performing more than one million calculations. And if this formula is copied to 10,000 cells then that means **10 billion calculations**. Reduce the ranges being referenced.

Comment: i need a method to decrease the range but to make it   50 rows above N and 50 rows below N, as example N100, need to Y50:150 , But N30, need Y1:Y80

Comment: Or if their other equation I can fill it to the end of the column, with different method make the performance faster

Comment: To significantly increase the complexity of the calculation, while narrowing your range/scope, you may not see much of an improvement... With the little information available, it sounds like VBA would be useful, but maybe that isn't necessary without understanding more of the rationale behind *why* you are doing this.  Maybe there is a better equation, but that's not something that can be inferred by the group here without significantly more information.

Comment: Solution :
ASIN(Information) : filter and remove the blanks , then copy the the table to other sheet to make VLOOKUP equation and returned to main sheet